# Transform and Visualize Similarity Matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, visualization, similarity

I'm working with a matrix that contains several entries and their similarity in the following format:

```
//      A      B      C  

 A      1     0.8    0.4

 B      0.8    1     0.2

 C      0.4   0.2     1
```

In this case, 1 means that two entries are identical, 0 that they are completely different. Each entry represents one string of observations that are either present or not. The similarity value is calculated by checking for overlapping observations. I would like to visualize this relation of the different entries; would it be possible to use a dendrogram in this case?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! This helps perfectly to identify similarities and differences. Would there be any possibility to show the 'interrelationships' between the different entries such an a dendrogram that groups the different entries by their similarity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two ways to visualize your matrix.

1. corrplot

   library(corrplot)
   corrplot(Mat)

[image: corrplot]

2. dendrogram using `hclust`

Your matrix is similarity but for `hclust`, we need *dis* similarity, so I will transform it using 1 - Mat.

```
HC = hclust(as.dist(1-Mat))
plot(HC)
```

[image: Dendrogram]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!